# Update table based on ID correspondence

Tags: mysql, inner-join, multiple-tables

I need to copy data from one table (A) to another (B) based on id correspondence, but the correspondence of ID is actually stored into a third table (C).
So the table with the correspondence looks like

```
C.A_ID  C.B_ID
1       33
2       56
3       74
```

I tried something like

```
UPDATE DB.A 
SET DB.A = DB.B
FROM DB.A p
INNER JOIN 
    DB.B p1
INNER JOIN
    DB.C p2
```

how to insert the ID correspondence?

Comment: Also you're missing the join condition. It's something like `A INNER JOIN B ON A.some_column = B.some_column`

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thanks to your comments I solved it in something like:
`insert into A(data)  
select *  
from (select C.ID_A, B.data  
from B join C  
on (B.id = C.ID_B)) tmp`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE A , (select c.id1, b.data from B join C on (B.id2 = C.id2 )) as Foo
SET A.data = Foo.data
WHERE
A.id1 = Foo.id1
```

Comment: As noted above I had to use _insert into_, but thanks to your example I was able to sort it out (see above)

Answer (score 0):

you need to use [select into](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select_into.asp) statement for selecting data from one table and insert in another table.